# Utility to automatically convert markdown content to HTML on-the-fly within an HTML page?

Tags: website, slideshow, markdown, pandoc, multimarkdown

Is there a utility that will automatically convert my Markdown content to HTML on-the-fly within an HTML page?

So that I could easily embed markdown content within an HTML page like so?

```
<BODY>
<div class="slide" id="what1">
<MARKDOWN>

# Blah blah blah.

Markdown *style* (content)[http://google.com]

</MARKDOWN>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the ability to use SSS (Server-Side-Script), and Perl, then **[this](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)** is for you.

It will convert your markdown language into HTML code while on the server.

---

**Or, instead, just convert it to HTML while on your computer, and then upload the HTML given.**

To do this, download the perl programming language [here](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) (unless you know that you already can run perl scripts).

Then, download the perl markdown script [here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) (this will convert markdown to HTML code).

Follow any installation instructions on the linked page.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know, how do I find out? I use Dreamhost, which I think is an Apache server...

Comment: Do you require it to convert the markdown language when the web page is loaded? Because if you don't, you can just run the perl script from your computer (which will convert it), and then upload the new HTML code. You get what I mean?

Comment: Check out my updated answer if you don't require it to convert on pageload.